# call method every 15 minutes

Tags: android

I will get latitude and longitude of android device using below code but I want updated latitude and longitude every 15 minute. How can I get this?

```
    package com.position.position;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Timer;
    import java.util.TimerTask;

    import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.os.Looper;
    import android.os.Message;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class Main extends Activity {
        StringBuilder stringBuilderlatitude = new StringBuilder();
         StringBuilder stringBuilderlongitude = new StringBuilder();
         public EditText NombreSeconde;
         public EditText NombreMetre;
         public float ValueNM;
         public int i=0;
        LocationManager locationManager;
        private String locationProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
        float numberMetre;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            Button BtnValider = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BtnValider);

            BtnValider.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override

                public void onClick(View v) {

                     NombreSeconde = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ValeurSeconde);
                     EditText NombreMetreEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ValeurMetre);
                    numberMetre = Float.valueOf(NombreMetreEditText.getText().toString());
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Paramètres enregistrés", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }

                });

            /////////////////////////////////////
            String locationContext = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(locationContext);
            //majCoordonnes();
```

**locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationProvider,100,100, new MajListener());**

```
        }
        ///////////////////////////

        //////////////////////////
        class MajListener implements android.location.LocationListener { 
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) { 
                stringBuilderlatitude= new StringBuilder();
                stringBuilderlongitude=new StringBuilder();


              majCoordonnes();


            }
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
            }
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){
            }
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
            }


         };

        public void majCoordonnes() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Mise à jour des coordonnées",200000).show();

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuilder.append("Fournisseurs :");
            List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true); 
            // Pour chaque fournisseur ...
            for (String provider : providers) {
               stringBuilder.append("\n");
               stringBuilder.append(provider);
               stringBuilder.append(" : ");
               // ... on affiche la position.
               Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
               String locationContext = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
               locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(locationContext);
               if (location != null) { 
                  double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                  double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                  stringBuilder.append(latitude);
                  stringBuilder.append(", ");
                  stringBuilder.append(longitude);
               } else {
                  stringBuilder.append("Non déterminée");
               }
            }

           // Log.i("MaPosition", stringBuilder.toString()); 
            TextView t=new TextView(this); 
            t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextResultat); 
            t.setText(stringBuilder.toString());


            ///////////////////////////////////// partie ajoute//////////////////////////
            LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
            Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();
            double latitude = location.getLatitude();


            stringBuilderlatitude.append(latitude);
            stringBuilderlongitude.append(longitude);


            String xlatitude=stringBuilderlatitude.toString();
            String xLongitude=stringBuilderlongitude.toString();

            Log.i("MaPosition","x1="+xlatitude +"x2="+ xLongitude);

            //Log.i("MaPosition", " apres append"+stringBuilderlatitude.toString()); 
            String y=stringBuilderlongitude.toString();
            stringBuilderlongitude.append(longitude);
             String result = "";
             ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("year","1980"));        
            try{
                Log.i("MaPosition", "Envoi les coordonnes au serveur"); 
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.kbma.site.com/insertGPS.php?latitude="+xlatitude.toString()+"&longitude="+xLongitude);
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Coordonnes envoyées au serveur kbma.site.com",200000).show();
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    InputStream is = entity.getContent();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    is.close();

                    result=sb.toString();

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                    Log.i("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
            }

         }
        /////////////////////////

        /////////////////

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Wow... you just dump **ALL** of your 192 lines of code here. Nobody is going to help if you just give us all of your code and say "Fix it"!

Comment: Maybe you want to use a Locatoin Poller instead doing in Activity. Visit https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll and have fun.

Comment: AlarmManager - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: @Squonk no need for AlarmManager... LocationManager already provides a parameter for you to use to specify how frequently you want updates.

Comment: @FoamyGuy : As the OP simply dumped a load of code in the question, my comment was based purely on the title "call method every 15 minutes". Also, based on the fact the OP's code is in an `Activity`, if I wanted to do the same thing (and it was mission critical), I'd use `AlarmManager` with an `IntentService` as there's no guarantee that the end-user wouldn't have left the `Activity`.

Answer (score 2):

You are already requesting location updates from the system, just increase the time of the frequency from 100 milliseconds to 15 mintutes. Change this line:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationProvider,100,100, new MajListener());
```

to this:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationProvider,(15 * 60 * 1000),100, new MajListener());
```

Note also that since you are inside of an Activity you are going to stop getting callbacks when the user navigates away from the activity.

If you want this to run in the background (and thus not get closed when the user navigates away) you will need to put it into a Service instead of an Activity

Answer (score 1):

This code updates location every 5 seconds (15 * 60 * 1000 milliseconds) OR 500 meter:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, (15 * 60 * 1000), 500, locationListener);
LocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener();

// ...

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        currentLocation = new GeoPoint(location);
        // ...
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
}
```